# Search cell for text and add if not found

Tags: excel, string, csv

I have a product spreadsheet that contains a row with file names of images.  Some have the file extension and some don't.  I am trying to figure out a way to avoid adding ".jpg" to an entire column of cells in my excel worksheet.  Is there a method that can help me search to see if the specified filename in the cell is already ending with .jpg?  At the same time is it possible to add .jpg if its not there?  I have tried with Concatenate and IF statement, but I am not having any luck.

Is there a function or method that can search if my cell contains the file extension(.jpg to be specific) and if nothing specified, is it possible to add one such as ".jpg"?

Answer (score 0):

I created the following spreadsheet, as you can see some of the values have the extension ".jpg" and some don't

```
A
```

1 one.jpg
2 two
3 three.jpg
4 four.jpg
5 five
6 six
7 seven.jpg
8 eight
9 nine.jpg

I am assuming that you meant you had a spreadsheet similar to the sample I typed here, with more entries

I google for a way to read the last 4 characters of a cell in excel, this gave me the =RIGHT(A1, 4), this means that wherever you type this formula you will get the last four characters of A1

So using IF + RIGHT + CONCATENATE I was able to read the values in the A column

If the last 4 characters in the A1 are the same as the string ".jpg" then just give me back the value of A1, if the last 4 character of A1 are NOT the same as the string ".jpg" then give me back the concatenation of A1 and the string ".jpg"

the formula is as follows

=IF(RIGHT(A1,4)=".jpg",A1,CONCATENATE(A1,".jpg"))

instead of using the string ".jpg" you can type the string in a cell and use the cell number.

I have this formula in column E, I first wrote in E1, I then copied it to the rest of the cells in column E, this means that a copy of column A is being created, I do not know if the formula can be changed so that the formula searches the cell/column where it is written.

I hope this is of some help, and if you see any errors, or know of a better way to do this feel free to correct/share, as I myself am learning

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to solve this using worksheet functions rather than VBA code, I would use some variation of the following:

```
=IF(RIGHT(A1, 4)=".jpg", A1, A1&".jpg")
```

This formula looks at cell A1 and adds .jpg to it if it doesn't already end in .jpg

I can't guess how to integrate it into your sheet but should give you a good start